# Ignore the rest of the python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python scripts often contain "executable code" (functions, classes, &c) in the first part of the file and "test code" (interactive experiments) at the end.

I want `python`, `py_compile`, `pylint` &c to completely ignore the experimental stuff at the end.

I am looking for something like `#if 0` for `cpp`.

**How can this be done?**

Here are some ideas and the reasons they are bad:

1. `sys.exit(0)`: works for `python` but not `py_compile` and `pylint`
2. put all experimental code under `def test():`: I can no longer copy/paste the code into a `python` REPL because it has non-trivial indent
3. put all experimental code between lines with `"""`: emacs no longer indents and fontifies the code properly
4. comment and uncomment the code all the time: I am too lazy (yes, this is a single key press, but I have to remember to do that!)
5. put the test code into a separate file: I want to keep the related stuff together

PS. My IDE is Emacs and my python interpreter is `pyspark`.

Comment: put test code into another file?

Comment: Any good IDE/text editor should have "toggle comment" function. It makes the whole comment/uncomment thing 1 click away. Why do you have it both in one file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ipython` rather than `python` for your REPL  It has better code completion and introspection and when you paste indented code it can automatically "de-indent" the pasted code.

Thus you can put your experimental code in a test function and then paste in parts without worrying and having to de-indent your code.

If you are pasting large blocks that can be considered individual blocks then you will need to use the `%paste` or `%cpaste` magics.

eg.

```
    for i in range(3):
        i *= 2 
        # with the following the blank line this is a complete block

        print(i)
```

With a normal paste:

```
In [1]:         for i in range(3):
   ...:                 i *= 2
   ...:     

In [2]:             print(i)
4
```

Using `%paste`

```
In [3]: %paste
        for i in range(10):
            i *= 2

            print(i)

## -- End pasted text --
0
2
4

In [4]:
```

#### PySpark and IPython

> It is also possible to launch PySpark in IPython, the enhanced Python interpreter. PySpark works with IPython 1.0.0 and later. To use IPython, set the IPYTHON variable to 1 when running bin/pyspark:<sup>[1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html)</sup>
>
> ```
> $ IPYTHON=1 ./bin/pyspark
> ```

Comment: Presumably the thrust of this answer is that `ipython` reduces the downside of option 2.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for clarifying that. I'm not always best at explaining the reasoning behind my thought processes.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no widely (or any) standard describing what you are talking about, so getting a bunch of python specific things to work like this will be difficult.

However, you could wrap these commands in such a way that they only read until a signifier. For example (assuming you are on a unix system):

```
cat $file | sed '/exit(0)/q' |sed '/exit(0)/d'
```

The command will read until 'exit(0)' is found. You could pipe this into your checkers, or create a temp file that your checkers read. You could create wrapper executable files on your path that *may* work with your editors.

Windows may be able to use a similar technique.

I might advise a different approach. Separate files might be best. You might explore iPython notebooks as a possible solution, but I'm not sure exactly what your use case is.

Answer (score 1):

With python-mode.el mark arbitrary chunks as section - for example via `py-sectionize-region`.

Than call `py-execute-section`.

Updated after comment:

python-mode.el is delivered by melpa.

M-x list-packages RET

Look for python-mode - the built-in python.el provides 'python, while python-mode.el provides 'python-mode.

Developement just moved hereto: https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode

Comment: the standard python mode which comes with emacs does not have sections. are you talking about `python-x`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow something like option 2.
I usually put experimental code in a main method.

```
def main ():
    *experimental code goes here *
```

Then if you want to execute the experimental code just call the main.

```
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think the standard ('Pythonic') way to deal with this is to do it like so:</strike>

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

def my_function():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # testing code here
```

**Edit after your comment**

I don't think what you want is possible using a plain Python interpreter. You could have a look at the IEP Python editor ([website](http://www.iep-project.org/), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/iep-project/iep)): it supports something like Matlab's cell mode, where a cell can be defined with a double comment character (`##`):

```
## main code

class MyClass(object):
    ...

def my_function():
    ...

## testing code

do_some_testing_please()
```

All code from a `##`-beginning line until either the next such line or end-of-file constitutes a single cell.
Whenever the cursor is within a particular cell and you strike some hotkey (default Ctrl+Enter), the code within that cell is executed in the currently running interpreter. An additional feature of IEP is that selected code can be executed with F9; a pretty standard feature but the nice thing here is that IEP will smartly deal with whitespace, so just selecting and pasting stuff from inside a method will automatically work.

Comment: @sds See my edit, I think you need particular editor/IDE features to do what you are after.

Comment: my ide is emacs; my repl is pyspark

Comment: Interesting to know why this was downvoted; the original option I mentioned is not exactly the OP's option 2 (it's slightly different because the testing code is not inside a method but in the 'standard' `if ...:` block at the end of a module). The second option I mentioned in my edit is really a genuine attempt at a solution; like I said I think it's not possible to achieve this with standard, non-tool-augmented, Python.

Comment: Hi there, downvoter here. I downvoted every answer on this question that seemed to me to be invalidated by a sufficient read-through of the question. For example, your first solution fails to address the _reason_ OP didn't use Option 2, namely that it does not use base-level indent. Your second solution fails to account for the fact that this breaks syntax highlighting in the IDE.

Comment: The `__name__ == '__main__'` check is not normally used for tests in particular, but in general for distinguishing whether the file is imported as a module or run as a script (i.e. to allow both).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: thanks for the explanation, much appreciated. I now see the error of my ways with regards to my first answer attempt. However, the second solution does *not* break syntax highlighting in an IDE; the code within a 'cell' (anything following a `##`-starting line until either the next such line or EOF) is normal Python code.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak Changed my vote. Admittedly I was a little torn on yours and mostly voted in context that this was getting a lot of fast but poor answers, and I didn't want new onlookers to be discouraged from answering.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a proper version control system to keep the "real" and the "experimental" parts separated.

For example, using Git, you could only include the real code without the experimental parts in your commits (using [`add -p`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging#Staging-Patches)), and then temporarily [`stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) the experimental parts for running your various tools.

You could also keep the experimental parts in their own branch which you then [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) on top of the non-experimental parts when you need them.

Comment: Then take advantage of it!

Comment: my question is orthogonal to version control. I do not want to make a commit for each comma I insert in a file.

Comment: Then I have no better ideas, sorry.

Comment: By the way, my suggestion does not have an implication of the granularity of your commits. The only requirement is that you keep the experimental and non-experimental parts separate.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to put tests as [*doctests*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) into the docstrings of your code, which admittedly is only practical for simpler cases.

This way, they are only treated as executable code by the `doctest` module, but as comments otherwise.